# i20 magna locking beep

Tags: central-locking, horn

I drive an Indian i20 magna+ 2019 model and need to stop the harsh beep sound while locking / unlocking. Does anyone know how to do it? Hyundai salesman said its not doable, wasnt that assuring.

Answer (score 1):

It is there as confirmation that you have locked - some owners forget.

Other owners lock the car, then as they turn to leave and put the keys in their pocket or bag manage to press unlock...

So it is for safety in both cases. If it really bugs you then find and disconnect the beeper or sounding device. But you might find that it has multiple functions....

Comment: Since i mostly park in a parking spot under someone's house i find it rude to  honk it at odd times. The person said now the main horn is used for lock sound it may not be possible to mute the sound. I was hoping if someone has an experience

Comment: Have they complained? Perhaps they have already ignored the noise... Don’t return at 3AM - come back at reasonble times :)

Comment: Haha! If the issue is not fixable i guess they have to learn to live with it

Comment: If they do comment, then saying that you did ask about it at the dealership shows consideration...